# Autocomplete forms of Internet Explorer 11, copy from one computer to another

Tags: windows, registry, internet-explorer-11

I have users who habitually use autocomplete forms in the Internet Explorer 11 browser.

When having to change them to other PC, we need to copy the data of this Internet Explorer 11 autocomplete from a computer to another.

I have seen information about it related about Windows 7, but the registry entries to which this information refers do not exist in Windows 10.

I have also seen a utility that promises to do so, but in reality it does not restore it afterwards. At least in my case.

It should not be too complex to copy this data, can someone help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been in contact with Windows support, they tell me that this option is not possible for security reasons. They also tell me that it is not advisable to use third-party software for this purpose, as well as making changes to the registry since it could stop working correctly.

I apologize if it were not correct to ask this question here.